# MS Dynamics CRM 2011: Can I Copy an Entity and Rename the Entity?

Tags: sql-server, copy, dynamics-crm-2011, entity, microsoft-dynamics

I need to create an entity with the EXACT same columns and metadata as one I already have.  I just need to give the new identity a different name as the data comes from a different customer and wanted to keep the entities separate; trying to be efficient in case I have to do this again.

Is this something I can do in MS Dynamics CRM 2011?

Also, will the ExtensionBase in Sql-Server be renamed to the new name if able to copy the entity is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create and export an unmanaged solution containing only the entity you want to duplicate. After you need to manually edit the solution xml and change the relevant entries (now I don't know exactly which one, but I think only the entity name plus something else).

After you import back this unmanaged solution and you will get the new entity.